# Слоги в слове "вопль"

Tags: слоги

Встретила такой вопрос: ***в каком пункте в выделенном слове два слога:***

а) *Я глупая, а ты умён,

Живой, а я остолбенелая.

О, ВОПЛЬ женщин всех времён:

"Мой милый, что тебе я сделала?"*

б) *И затихают шорохи и вздохи,

И замолкают птичьи голоса,

И ВОПЛЬ певца из струнной суматохи,

Как вольный беркут, мчится в небеса.*

в) *И заглушают ли гулы славы

ВОПЛЬ здесь встающих голосов,

Где первой вольности предтечи

Легли под взрывами картечи!*

Answer (score 5):

В слове вопль один слог, так как один гласный. Возможно, речь идет о фонетическом слове, тогда это под цифрой 2 (И ВОПЛЬ - произносится как одно слово).

Answer (score 3):

В варианте А) слово произносится в два слога, укладываясь в стихотворный метр.

Comment: Правильно, только подробнее надо бы. И с пунктом В - неточность.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь в случае а) слово вопль произносится в два слога: [вопъль]; - ъ - здесь редкая для русского языка сверхкраткая гласная (шва), которая возникает под рудиментарным действием закона открытого слога перед Л и Р внутри скоплений согласных (или в абсолютном конце слова). Обычно в фонетической записи не фиксируется, но иногда в стихотворных текстах усиливается до полноценного слога, порождая нечто срелнее между Э и Ы.

В пункте А) у Цветаевой имеет место именно такой случай.

Я глупая, а ты умён,
Живой, а я остолбенелая.
О, ВОПЛЬ женщин всех времён:
"Мой милый, что тебе я сделала?"
(написано на рубеже 1910-х - 1920-х, опубликовано много позже, в 1941).

Ритмическая схема - четырехстопный ямб  (с заметрическими тактами в четных строках).
-/-/-/-/
-/-/-/-/--
-/-/-/-/
-/-/-/-/--

Тут ясно, что на "вопль" попадает два метрических слога.

Насколько понимаю, подобное вообще было в моде у поэтов Серебряного века.

Вот еще пример.

Ревет сынок. Побит за двойку с плюсом.
Жена на локоны взяла последний **рубль**,
Супруг, убитый лавочкой и флюсом,
Подсчитывает месячную **убыль**.
Саша Черный, 1909

"Рубль" рифмуется с "убыль", трудно не признать, что в нем два слога.

В двух других примерах (Заболоцкий и Брюсов) такого не наблюдается.

Пункт В) воспроизведен неправильно. У Брюсова -

И **заглушат** ли гулы славы
ВОПЛЬ здесь встающих голосов,
Где первой вольности предтечи
Легли под взрывами картечи

Догадка Ларf не верна, ибо не отвечает на вопрос по сути.